# MOSFET IRF740 and 3,6 V

Tags: mosfet, esp8266

I'm looking for a way to completely shutdown power supply to two Modules (UltraSound HC-SR04 and a 433 MHz transmitter unit) while the ESP8266 Module is in deep sleep mode.
I bought some MOSFET IRF740 units because they were recommended by the clerk in the electronics store for that kind of undertaking.
I wired everything the way I think It's supposed to:
Gate = GPIO 14
Drain = Ground of HC-SR04 and 433 MHz
Source = Minus From the Circuit
The Whole system is powered via 3 1,2 V Batteries so there's 3,6 Volt

Problem:
I defined the ping as output and set it to low to test the whole thing but there was still a reading from the HC-SR04 Module although this should only be possible if the ping is HIGH?

Question:
Is my setup wrong... Did I misread the purposes of a MOSFET? Is 3,6 V not enough to switch the system from Power On to Power Off?

I edited the code a bit and found out that it works if I putting the Pin on LOW twice ... ?
So like this:

```
const int GATE_PIN = 14;
digitalWrite(GATE_PIN,LOW); //SensorPower --> OFF
digitalWrite(GATE_PIN,LOW); //SensorPower --> OFF
```

this sets the Pin to low and the MOSFET switches

Comment: Schematic? A N channel fet should turn off when the gate is pulled low.

Comment: OK so it should work with 3,6 Volt....?

Comment: An IRF740 *starts* to turn on when the gate is 4V above the drain. So no, 3.6V is not enough. Getting sufficient gate voltage is the downside of FETs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The threshold voltage is the minimum voltage required so that the transistor starts to conduct. And you need more than this to put it into saturation.

The Vth (threshold voltage) of the IRF 740 is min=2v, max=4v so definitely you're in unchartered territory.

Moreover let's look at this graphic:
[image]

You need at least 4V to have 100mA (although with a 50V drain voltage).

To power off, specially since you might have ground planes I strongly believe it's better to use a P mosfet to cut the (+) side of the supply. The schematic would look something like this:

[image]

Control input is your microcontroller. This turns on/off a logic NMOS. When it's on the current passing is very little because it's limited by a 1Mohm resistor.

While turned on it forces ground on the gate of the PMOS, thus, turning it on and allowing power.

When the control input is low, the NMOS is off. The 1Mohm resistor pulls up the gate of the PMOS and it's off. With this simple circuit you can control power to your loads. If your microcontroller will shutdown the pin and turn it off, make sure you put a pulldown to the pin so the NMOS stays off when the microcontroller pin is in High-Z while asleep.

Hope it helps

Comment: The second FET is unnecessary. Plenty of logic level Fets that can handle the current this needs.

Comment: Thanks for the 2 MOS solution. I am not quit sure I understand where I have to put the pulldown in that scenario.

Comment: @passerby: which FET would you recommend?

Comment: STN4NF03L seems good. No personal experience with it though. But the problem is that regardless of the mosfet you use, if your current circuit or code does not turn off the IRF740 when the pin is pulled to ground, then changing the FET won't change that.

Comment: No it seems i got that to work .. I edited my question

Comment: Maybe right no the whole setup works because the batteries are fully charged and provide 3.85 Volt ... I'll look into the STN4NF03L

Comment: @Passerby both fets are needed, unless the microcontroller can input the vin voltage, i.e. you wanna turn off 3.3 volt and that's your pin output as well.

Ussually not the case, if you want to control 5v with a 3.3 microcontroller you can't otherwise.

Comment: @Andres that's exactly what you can do with an n channel fet or NPN transistor as a low side driver. As long as you can pull the gate or base close to the emitter or source, in this case 0v, then it will work. Any given low side driver can control a voltage much higher than it's input to the gate or base.

Comment: @Passerby yes you can do as well low or high-side. You would ussually have a ground plane, which makes cutting the ground annoying because you have to cut the plane or a lot of lines, whereas it's ussually easier with cutting the (+V) side. If you think EMC/PCB Design/practicality/etc, high-side is the way to go

Comment: I tried a simple approach and it seems to work --> Since the HC-SR04 UltraSound Sensor and the 433 MHz draw very little (6mA and 9 mA) and the Maximum Output of the ESP8266 12 F is 12 i use two different Digital Out Pins to power the Sensor and the module for a short time (not both at the same time) --> works great and the Power consumption looks great --> 10 Hours and the VCC is still at 3.81 which was the starting VCC

Comment: Small follow up question: I drive a 12V/10W LED with a 12V/1.5A AC DC converter via an IRL740 whose gate is directly connected to an AtTiny85 PWM pin. The Tiny is also driven by the 12V DC via a 5V step down module (AMS1117-5V), so I should get a full 5V PWM signal to the gate, which should be sufficient to power the LED. Nevertheless I only get around 20mA over the LED. IRL740 should deliver much more at 5V following the data sheet. Is this connected to the small current delivered from the PWM pin (around 20-40mA as the net claims)? I switched to an IRL540 and got around 650mA trough the LED.